# How do you get an existing Web2py app deployed on OpenShift?

Tags: git, web2py, openshift

I'm trying to get an existing web2py app deployed on OpenShift.

I'm doing the following -

1) Create and Setup OpenShift app - https://github.com/prelegalwonder/openshift_web2py

I followed the instructions given and got the welcome app running on OpenShift. It created a new repo on OpenShift and the app works.

2) Merge Existing Repo with OpenShift repo - https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1006-sync-new-git-repo-with-your-own-existing-git-repo

I merged the OpenShift repo with my existing repo (which has the web2py app). I resolved the conflicts. It works locally.

But when I push it to OpenShift it does the following

The git command never terminates - but when I do a git status it shows that it's gone through. I don't see the OpenShift build info I saw when I deployed the first time

The app itself shows no change - it still behaves like the welcome controller from the first set of instructions.

After a while I get a 503 and I see from the OpenShift dashboard that the app is building.

The status hasn't changed in a while - exactly what is happening / what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting in your git push logs?  And your application logs?  A common issue is the directory layout mismatch so you may want to compare the quickstart's repo vs yours.  If you are still having issues, please post a link to your github repo to try.  Also post to our [forums](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift) in case other users may have more ideas.

Comment: Thanks Nam - you. were right merging the repos didn't really make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took a different approach.

I setup the app from the first link.Then I used the administrative interface to install the app from a package I created of the app locally.

The app got installed ( facing a weird dependency related issue but that's not related to the above)